# Why can I not watch YouTube videos on Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer, youtube

I used to be able to watch YouTube videos with no problems, but at some point in the last several weeks, something went wrong. Whenever I try to watch a video, it says

> This video is unavailable with the Education Filter enabled. To view this video, the site network administrator will need to add it to a playlist

The network does not have an Education Filter (all other computers at home & work can view YouTube videos fine), videos work fine on Ubuntu, and *even weirder*, they work fine on Internet Explorer!

I have the most recent version of Adobe Flash Player and the most recent version of Chrome. Can someone show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Michel's answer, if you want to delete cookies just for youtube in chrome:
Go to Settings > Show advanced settings > Contents settings > All cookies and site data > then search for "youtube" and individually delete all the cookies that show up in the search.[image]

If that doesn't work, as Michel said, try uninstalling and reinstalling chrome

Comment: This helped me to start getting normal YouTube again after always getting the mobile version (useless). So simple and so effective.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to clear Chrome Youtube cookies.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/938037

If it doesn't work, try to uninstall flash, then Chrome, then re-install everything.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried everything, but figured something out that finally worked for me:
1.I just right clicked on the video that was playing, clicked on 'About the HTML5 player'
2. Check correct the option that says, 'The HTML5 player is currently used when possible.'

And go back, refresh the video and enjoy! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I already confirmed the other answer worked for me.